# How change Windows Font Explorer test phrase

Tags: windows, windows-8, fonts

How I can change font test phrase in Windows 8.1. I need to see if font have another characters set.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older Windows versions it was as simple as hex editing FontView.exe.

In Windows 7 you can use Resource Hacker to edit a copy of `Windows\System32\en-US\fontview.exe.mui` (obviously replace en-US with your system's language code), compile script when you're done, save and replace the original:

[image]

This might work in Windows 8.x too. You may face a problem with Windows complaining about OS files being replaced however. As quadronom said it's best to use a third-party font viewer. There are tons of good free ones available.

---

Factoid: Apparently Windows ME and XP had alternate preview strings available for en-US besides "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" (for ME it was "Windows Millennium Edition" and for XP see below) which would show up based on locale settings and supported font code page tables, but Vista dropped them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
It's always in the same language as the as the OS. So e.g. my text is on german. You should use a 3rd party software for viewing the fonts, there you can change the text.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this doesn't work in Windows 11. I edited the phrase in fontview.exe.mui, replaced the file with the edited one, restarted the computer but the Font Viewer still displays the original text.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1210473)